# Finding Nth Fibonacci Number in O(logn) time and space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, fibonacci

I am trying to find the Nth Fibonacci number in O(logn) time. We can do O(logn) solution by using the Fibonacci Q matrix.

[image]

But, there is another [solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/) by using the [Cassini and Catalan identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities) to find the Nth Fibonacci number in O(logn) time. It states below:

> If n is even then k = n/2: F(n) = [2*F(k-1) + F(k)]*F(k)
>
> If n is odd then k = (n + 1)/2: F(n) = F(k)*F(k) + F(k-1)*F(k-1)

I could understand the proof only upto the marked equation:

[image]

But, I am not understanding the below equations and the final derived equations.

Can anyone please explain in details? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you compute the determinant of `{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}`?

Comment: Yes. It's (-1).

Comment: Correct. And `det(A^n)` is `(det(A))^n`. That gives you LHS of the equation, `(-1)^n`. RHS is a determinant of the RHS matrix, which I am sure you can compute as well.

Comment: You got my query wrong. I understood until this point as described in the question description. I am not understanding the below two equations. How the final equation derived that part I am not understanding.

Comment: Got you. It is very hard to express here (this site does not support LaTeX). The idea is that since you know the matrix form of `{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}^(n+m)`, _and_ the matrix form of `{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}^n` _and_ {{1, 1}, {1, 0}}^m`, do the matrix multiplication of the latter two. It must be equal to the first one. Here you will obtain the identity. For a more detailed explanation, ask at math stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the idea is to take this matrix product

```
 |1 1|^n   |1 1|^m    |1 1|^{m+n}
 |1 0|   x |1 0|    = |1 0|
```

and use the fact that this can be rewritten as

```
 |F_{n+1}    F_n    |   |F_{m+1}    F_m    |   |F_{m+n+1}    F_{m+n}  |
 |                  | x |                  | = |                      |
 |F_n        F_{n-1}|   |F_m        F_{m-1}|   |F_{m+n}      F_{m+n-1}|
```

Now, multiply the matrices on the left using the standard matrix product formula. You get this reuslt:

```
|F_{n+1} F_{m+1} + F_n F_m    F_{n+1}F_m + F_n F_{m-1}  |   |F_{m+n+1}    F_{m+n}  |
|                                                       | = |                      |
|F_n F_{m+1} + F_{n-1} F_m    F_n F_m + F_{n-1} F_{m-1} |   |F_{m+n}      F_{m+n-1}|
```

This gives these four equations:

- F<sub>n+1</sub>F<sub>m+1</sub> + F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>m</sub> = F<sub>m+n+1</sub>
- F<sub>n+1</sub>F<sub>m</sub> + F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>m-1</sub> = F<sub>m+n</sub>
- F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>m+1</sub> + F<sub>n-1</sub>F<sub>m</sub> = F<sub>m+n</sub>
- F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>m</sub> + F<sub>n-1</sub>F<sub>m-1</sub> = F<sub>m+n-1</sub>

The remaining equalities fall out from just substituting in specific values of m and n.